# Get instance count of a specific class in Objective-C/IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

For QA purposes I want to ensure that instances of specific classes have  been deallocated properly (so the actual count of instances is sufficient). I looked into the Objective-C runtime reference, but I could not find the appropriate function. I have checked similar questions but did not find a satisfying answer.

**Edit**
I took TheCodingArt's mockup and completed it, the result can be obtained at
https://www.generomobile.de/gmi/allocchecker.m
The difficulty was to swizzle dealloc because ARC forbids passing the selector of dealloc for swizzling. I stumbled across this interesting swizzling tutorial at http://defagos.github.io/yet_another_article_about_method_swizzling/
NSString and other class clusters obviously are not freed by dealloc as one can see in the sample. But for my own classes it works our current IOS project and gives some interesting insights.

Comment: Use the *Instruments* leak tool.  Don't be looking at no retain counts now else the Objective-C Elders will downvote you.

Comment: The QA tests run outside the leak tool. I'm interestest in knowing if its possible to enumerate the instances of a particular class at runtime. Possible or not ?

Comment: Not without additional coding in the class (i.e. static array holding each (weak) instance).  Sounds like a bit of a nightmare.

Comment: I was hoping it can be done via the self introspection facilities of objective C, but apparently not. Of course adding a static counter in the classes of interest is the obvious method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per request, I've mocked up a category that will keep count of allocated objects using method swizzling and a singleton. This was a quick mock up, so there are a few issues with it (one being that initializing anything that is contained within the storage class will cause an infinite loop). Mind you, this is for keeping track of many objects and should not be used in a production environment. The best methodology overall is to use the instruments tool.

```
#import "NSObject+Initializer.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@interface ObjectCounter : NSObject

+ (instancetype)sharedObjectCounter;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *objectCounterDictionary;

@end

@implementation ObjectCounter

+ (instancetype)sharedObjectCounter
{
    static ObjectCounter *objectCounter;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        objectCounter = [ObjectCounter new];
        objectCounter.objectCounterDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    });
    return objectCounter;
}

@end


@implementation NSObject (Initializer)



+ (NSNumber *)initializedCount
{
    NSLog(@"Dict: %@", [ObjectCounter sharedObjectCounter].objectCounterDictionary);
    return [ObjectCounter sharedObjectCounter].objectCounterDictionary[NSStringFromClass([self class])];
}

+ (id)alloc_swizzled
{
    NSLog(@"Swizzled");
    NSString *className = NSStringFromClass([self class]);
    if (![className isEqualToString:NSStringFromClass([NSMutableDictionary class])] && ![className isEqualToString:NSStringFromClass([ObjectCounter class])]) {
        ObjectCounter *counter = [ObjectCounter sharedObjectCounter];
        NSMutableDictionary *objectDictionary = counter.objectCounterDictionary;
        NSNumber *count = objectDictionary[className];
        count = count ? @(count.integerValue + 1) : @0;
        objectDictionary[className] = count;
    }

    return [self alloc_swizzled];
}


+ (void)load
{

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        Class class = [self class];

        SEL originalSelector = @selector(alloc);
        SEL swizzledSelector = @selector(alloc_swizzled);

        Method originalMethod = class_getClassMethod(class, originalSelector);
        Method swizzledMethod = class_getClassMethod(class, swizzledSelector);

        BOOL didAddMethod = class_addMethod(class, originalSelector, method_getImplementation(swizzledMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(swizzledMethod));

        if (didAddMethod) {
            class_replaceMethod(class, swizzledSelector, method_getImplementation(originalMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod));
        } else {
            method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I only made this per request, in no way is this a recommended methodology and if you read my answer you'll note that I note that. No need to down vote it....

Comment: it took a while but I could finally take your idea.I avoided any ObjC classes for counting the instances (Used CFMutableDictionary), also I used fprintf for traces because NSLog allocates objC objects itself . One question to your mockup remains: why you use dispatch_once to init the swizzling? is there a situation where load can be called twice ?

Comment: The dispatch_once ensures thread safety and it only runs once. It's been a while but I believe I found a weird edge case where this was needed. Could have been an inheritance thing but I don't remember. Regardless, it ensures proper behavior.

Comment: Ok understand. But to be thread safe the access to the ObjectCounter in your mockup would need to be synchronized too,AFAIK NSMutableDictionary is not thread safe per se.

Comment: That's true and I think I originally had NSCache or something as a quick job (I really didn't spend too much time writing this and just needed a quick solution). I would have added a custom serial queue if I needed that functionality. In that case just wrap an add/remove method with a private instance variable of the dict where it always pipes to the serial queue when setting/getting variables. In the case I noted, I believe I saw an issue instantly and just addressed it this way.

Comment: According to this exchange I changed my sample to handle threads. Thanks for sharing ideas!

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to setup a static counter in your .m file. Increment the counter in the designated `init` method and decrement the counter in the `dealloc` method. Provide a class method to read the count value.

Don't do this as a rule. This should only be done for testing.

Lets say you want to track the instance count of `SomeClass`. You can do:

**SomeClass.h**

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject

+ (NSInteger)instanceCount;

// everything else you need

@end
```

**SomeClass.m**

```
@import "SomeClass.h"

static NSInteger instanceCount = 0;

@implementation SomeClass

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        instanceCount++;
        // everything else you need
    }

    return self;
}

// all your other code

+ (NSInteger)instanceCount {
    return instanceCount;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    instanceCount--;
}

@end
```

Comment: yep ... i have two statics : lifeTimeInstances, and numberOfInstances. Also for each instance i have an instance property instanceNumber. Invaluable time saver (macros, not in release build) coupled with some 'self obligated' class templates.

Comment: Better yet, you could put this in a dictionary on a protocol for NSObject. You'd then be able to store [self class] as the key and an instantiation count as the object.

Comment: @TheCodingArt You should post an answer with your solution since it sounds much different than mine.

Comment: @TheCodingArt I'd be interest too in seeing a snippet

Comment: I meant category, apologies

Comment: I added a swizzling method category for example code via an answer. This will count anything (but whatever you exclude) that inherits from NSObject and add it into a count in a dictionary. Mind you, there are situations where you have to avoid an infinite loop via allocating the counting singleton object (hence my checks). I didn't want to put much time into this and just wanted to provide an example of what you could do.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a count without subclassing by adding a category and overriding alloc, This is really hacky but it's fine for testing and good for classes you don't own.  I have no idea if this would work without ARC.

```
@implementation UILabel (LableCounter)
static NSInteger labelCount = 0;
+ (id)alloc
{
    labelCount++;
    return [super alloc];
}
-(void)dealloc{
    labelCount--;
}
@end
```

Comment: No, do not do this. Categories must not attempt to override methods. It is undefined behavior.

Comment: [super alloc] in a category method is also bad, bad, bad! Say you instantiate an NSObject this way. In that case there is no `[super alloc]` because there's no superclass for NSObject!

Comment: The only reason this hack works is that it's effectively calling up the inheritance chain to [NSObject alloc] in the category's alloc. So yes this wouldn't work for NSObject itself.

Comment: Actually you can completely do this, you just have to swizzle the methods @rmaddy

Comment: @Dave The problem is that this hack doesn't work. Actually the bigger problem is that is might work or it might not work. There is no guarantee that the overridden methods provided in the category will actually be called. As I said earlier, overriding methods in a category is undefined behavior. It may or may not work. It must not be done.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085479/override-a-method-via-objc-category-and-call-the-default-implementation